# Notification Channels Android Oreo - Lights Color - Defaults

Tags: notifications, channel, android-8.0-oreo

I tried to use a notification channel on Android 8 (Nexus 5x) without a positive result. The notification comes with defaults. I want to change lights, vibration, etc.. Did someone use the new notification channel system with API 26 (with success)? BTW the import is from the v4 support lib and here is the main part of the code:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String id = context.getString(R.string.app_name)+"_"+context.getString(R.string.notification);
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name)+" - "+context.getString(R.string.reminder));
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        //mBuilder.setVibrate(Utils.VIBRATION_3_1000);
        mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary));
mBuilder.setContentText(context.getString(R.string.reminder));
       // mBuilder.setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 1000, 500);
        mBuilder.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Just in case, remember that channel defaults cannot be changed after their creation (only the name and description can be changed). If you created the channel once and then you tried to modify the defaults it won't work. You need to clear the application data or uninstall the app and then create the channels again from scratch.

Comment: This is done every time I click on the button, but only for test. So it should work.. because also for the first time the channel created is the same, with custom parameters.

Comment: Fine, after some new test I realised that the channel was created before my changes. So changing the name of the channel (or uninstalling/clearing app data) fixed my problem. Thanks

Comment: How to create the `resultPendingIntent` if I may ask?

Comment: @hamena314 I think you can find plenty of pages about that on stackoverflow, btw here is my working code:
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, FromNotificationActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationID);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(notificationID, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


as you can see in that case I needed to open an activity from the notification.